# Crashes in UIAnalyticsGatherMutitouchAnalytics

Tags: ios, uikit, analytics, crash-reports, multi-touch

I have a strange rare crashes in my iOS app.
[image]
The stack-trace shows a function `_UIAnalyticsGatherMutitouchAnalytics`, for which I can't find any info.
**There's no intentional analytics in the project**, so I suppose Apple gathers it by itself.

I've set a symbolic breakpoint to both `_UIAnalyticsGatherMutitouchAnalytics` and `UIAnalyticsGatherMutitouchAnalytics`: no hits.

While the stack-trace doesn't contain a custom code, I suppose this multitouch analytics is gathered when the user works with a custom `UIVIew`.

This view has a complex logic of processing touches inside `touchesBegan/touchesBegan/touchesEnded`:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

and also has a gesture recognizers for 3 fingers:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleThreeFingersSwipeLeft)];
[swipeLeft setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];                        
[swipeLeft setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[swipeLeft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:3];
```

I have no ideas what to look next, **so the questions are**:  
1. When/why the crash in "UIAnalyticsGatherMutitouchAnalytics" can happen? 
2. Can the touch handling code I provided be related to the crash? 
3. Can this be a bug of Apple?  
4. Is there a way to disable this analytics?

Any comments are highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** 
I've set a symbolic breakpoint to `[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:]`, it fires on each touch. But there's no stacktrace, so I'm not sure this is caused by analytics:
[image]

Comment: No answers, unfortunately, but our app is also showing crashes with a very similar stack trace.

Comment: @Laura Thanks for sharing. Do you have any insights if it's related to a particular iOS version? E.g. crashes appeared after the users updated to 13.0 etc ?

Comment: They all seem to be iPads running 13.3.1.  I've had 3 crashes so far.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with same device and iOS version mentioned here. This is almost certainly an Apple issue, hopefully this has been addressed in 13.4 already or Apple knows about it as Xcode Organiser lists the issue as well and I hope Apple collects these fixes to scan for internal issues as well. You can as well report it using the Feedback Assistant just for sure.

Comment: @Laura Thanks, I viewed crash reports again, they all have iOS 13.3.1 also.

Comment: @Michi Thanks, I've reported a crash using the Feedback Assistant.